# How to access eth wallet with utc file

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

I have only saved the UTC file generated from myetherwallet and after losing data from my laptop i lost the document where i had my password and private key. Can i recover my account now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the file you have contains your private key, but it's encrypted with a password. If you no longer have that password, you can't decrypt it.

Comment: Is there a program for brute force ? i remember words but not the exact order

Comment: There almost certainly are, but I'm not familiar with any, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

By UTC file, do you mean the JSON keystore file?  It should follow roughly [this format](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Accounts,_Addresses,_Public_And_Private_Keys,_And_Tokens#UTC_JSON_Keystore_File).

You can attempt to brute force your password with [pyethrecover](https://github.com/burjorjee/pyethrecover).

Answer (score 0):

You can brute force your password if you have hint of password. You have to use hashcat but hashcat and jtr showing error that's you have to setup hashcat properly to use it and decrypt your wallet sucessfully
Which version UTC file you have.
If you need more help how to set up hashcat for ethereum and commands visit my profile